# Переиспользование переменных из общего класса в других классах (методах)

Tags: java

не так давно занимаюсь изучением Java, сейчас столкнулся с достаточно простой (на первой взгляд) задачей, которую не могу решить уже 2 дня. Смысл в том, что я планирую использовать пользовательский ввод (для двух переменных ("u" и "a")).
Изначально планировалось использовать переменные по аналогии с переменными "GRAVITY" и "t",

```
public class BallSettings {
    private static final float GRAVITY = 9.81f; //Сила гравитации
    private static final float t = 0.0f; //Расчет координат начинается с 0 секунд.
```

но я не могу сделать переменную "reader" статичной (во всяком случае был какой-то пост, что так вроде как можно сделать, но неправильно (информацию как сделать ее статичной я не нашел, к сожалению))

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

В общем сама задача заключается в том, чтобы использовать переменные "u", "a", для которых передается ввод пользователем тип double:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
private String pre_U = reader.readLine();
private String pre_A = reader.readLine();
private float u = Float.parseFloat(pre_U);
private float a = Float.parseFloat(pre_A);
```

Но таким образом, чтобы я мог эти переменные добавить в другой класс (методы x_coordinates и y_coordinates) (вместо статических значений "40.0f"и "70.0f"):

```
public static class Up7 extends JFrame {
    //Передача пользовательских параметров броска:
    /*
    //Организовать пользовательский ввод данных (!!!):
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String pre_U = reader.readLine();
    String pre_A = reader.readLine();
    float U = Float.parseFloat(pre_U);
    float A = Float.parseFloat(pre_A);
             */
    //static int[] x;
    //static int[] y;
    static int[] x = x_coordinates(40.0f, 70.0f, GRAVITY, t);
    static int[] y = y_coordinates(40.0f, 70.0f, GRAVITY, t);
    static int n = 101;


    public Up7() {
        super("Траектория движения тела");
        JPanel jcp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        setContentPane(jcp);
        jcp.add(new DrawingComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jcp.setBackground(Color.gray);
        setSize(2000, 1040);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    //Добавление кнопки:
    JButton btn = new JButton("Добавить шарик");
}
```

**Весь код (если потребуется):**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BallSettings {
    private static final float GRAVITY = 9.81f; //Сила гравитации
    private static final float t = 0.0f; //Расчет координат начинается с 0 секунд.
    public float u;
    public float a;
    /*
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    private String pre_U = reader.readLine();
    private String pre_A = reader.readLine();
    //считываение   вещественного   числа типа  float
    private float u = Float.parseFloat(pre_U);
    private float a = Float.parseFloat(pre_A);
*/

    /*
    public void Reader {
        //Организовать пользовательский ввод данных (!!!):

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String pre_U = reader.readLine();
        String pre_A = reader.readLine();
        //считываение   вещественного   числа типа  float
        float U = Float.parseFloat(pre_U);
        float A = Float.parseFloat(pre_A);
    }


     */

    public BallSettings (float u, float a) {
        this.u = u;
        this.a = a;
    }

    public float getU() {
        return u;
    }

    public float getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public BallSettings () {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Up7().setVisible(true);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String pre_U = reader.readLine();
        String pre_A = reader.readLine();
        float U = Float.parseFloat(pre_U);
        float A = Float.parseFloat(pre_A);


        BallSettings ball = new BallSettings();
        ball.a = 231;
        ball.u = 321;
        ball.getA();

        /*
        Up7.x = x_coordinates(U, A, GRAVITY, t);
        Up7.y = y_coordinates(U, A, GRAVITY, t);

         */

    }

    /* Расчет вертикального положения тела через 1 сек
     *
     * @param u - начальная скорость тела (м/с)
     * @param a - угол под которым брошено тело
     * @param g - сила гравитации
     * @param t - время движения (с)
     */

    public static int[] x_coordinates  (float u, float a, float g, float t) {

        float tpol = (float) ((2 * u * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(a))) / g);
        float tpol_100 = tpol / 100;
        double preX;
        int x;
        int[] XlistNew = new int[101];
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i ++) {
            preX =  (u * t * (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(a)))) ;
            preX = preX * 10;
            x = (int) preX;
            XlistNew[i] = x;
            System.out.println("t: " + t);
            System.out.println("tpol: " + tpol);
            System.out.println("tpol_100: " + tpol_100);
            System.out.println("preX: " + preX);
            System.out.println("X: " + XlistNew[i]);
            t = t + tpol_100;
        }
        return XlistNew;
    }

    public static int[] y_coordinates  (float u, float a, float g, float t) {
        float tpol = (float) ((2 * u * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(a))) / g);
        float tpol_100 = tpol / 100;
        double preY;
        int y;
        int[] YlistNew = new int[101];

        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i ++) {
            preY = (u * t * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(a)) - ((g * (t * t)) / 2));
            preY = 1000 - (preY * 10);
            y = (int) preY;
            YlistNew[i] = y;
            System.out.println("preY: " + preY);
            System.out.println("Y: " + YlistNew[i]);

            t = t + tpol_100;
        }
        return YlistNew;
    }


    static class DrawingComponent extends JPanel {
        int xg[] = Up7.x;
        int yg[] = Up7.y;
        int ng = Up7.n;
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics gh) {
            Graphics2D drp = (Graphics2D) gh;
            drp.drawPolyline(xg, yg, ng);
            //Прорисовка шара
            gh.fillOval(-10, 990, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    public static class Up7 extends JFrame {
        //Передача пользовательских параметров броска:
        /*
        //Организовать пользовательский ввод данных (!!!):
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String pre_U = reader.readLine();
        String pre_A = reader.readLine();
        float U = Float.parseFloat(pre_U);
        float A = Float.parseFloat(pre_A);
                 */
        //static int[] x;
        //static int[] y;
        static int[] x = x_coordinates(40.0f, 70.0f, GRAVITY, t);
        static int[] y = y_coordinates(40.0f, 70.0f, GRAVITY, t);
        static int n = 101;


        public Up7() {
            super("Траектория движения тела");

            JPanel jcp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            setContentPane(jcp);
            jcp.add(new DrawingComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jcp.setBackground(Color.gray);
            setSize(2000, 1040);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
        //Добавление кнопки:
        JButton btn = new JButton("Добавить шарик");
    }

}
```

Comment: Понимаю, что вполне вероятны типичные проблемы с архитектурой. Буду рад любой обратной связи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Во первых надо давать понятные имена переменным.

Comment: Где пользователь задает значения переменным? в командной строке? Что именно не получается получить данные введенные пользователем или передать их куда-то, или не отображаются изменения? уточните вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Z.John, 

Вроде как названия переменных более менее отражают суть:
     param u - начальная скорость тела (м/с)
     param a - угол под которым брошено тело

Уточнение вопроса: планирую передавать данные через консоль и получать их в переменные "a" и "u". Затем использовать этим переменные для методов "x_coordinates" и "y_coordinates" внутри класса Up7. Если Вы подскажите где правильнее эти переменные "принимать", чтобы потом переиспользовать в других классах (например, как переменные "GRAVITY" и "t" имеющие следующие типы приватности "private static final" ) - буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Если криво написал - извиняюсь заранее.

Comment: Как вариант сделать окно на нем два поля в котором пользователь задает значение и ниже панель с отрисовкой. Но если принципиально через командную строку то это тоже можно сделать

Comment: @Z.John Спасибо за правильные вопросы. Изначально вариант поля я вообще не рассматривал. На данном этапе все параметры привык передавать через консоль, но рад, что в "ответах" помогли реализовать именно через консоль. Возможно, в качестве последующей модернизации кода добавлю поля для ввода координат и уйду от консоли. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код запредельно сложный для такой простой задачи. Посему мои рекомендации таковы: во-первых, старайтесь как можно меньше использовать статику, во-вторых, избегайте дублирования кода, в-третьих, даже при хорошей документации переменные с названием a,f,g,n и т,д, недопустимы, поскольку это сильно ухудшает читаемость кода (это исправите сами), в-четвертых, не используйте "магические числа", в-пятых, всегда придерживайтесь правил именования классов,методов,переменных (и т.д. по конвенции) и последнее - почитайте про GRASP.

На быструю руку получилось примерно так...
В метод main добавите свой консольный ввод (используйте Scanner для консольного ввода, потребуется меньше кода).

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public final class Up7 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 920383437232026378L;

    private final CoordinateSetting coordinateSetting;

    public Up7(CoordinateSetting coordinateSetting) {        
        super("Траектория движения тела");
        this.coordinateSetting = coordinateSetting;
        setContentPane(new DrawingComponent());
        setSize(2000, 1040);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class DrawingComponent extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1165965120799250006L;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics gh) {
            gh.drawPolyline(coordinateSetting.getCoordinatesX(), coordinateSetting.getCoordinatesY(), coordinateSetting.getN());
            //Прорисовка шара
            gh.fillOval(-10, 990, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double u = 40, a = 70, g = 9.81, t = 0;
        int n = 101;

        new Up7(new CoordinateSetting(u, a, g, t, n));
    }

}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface CoordinateCalculator {
    public double calculate (double u, double a, double g, double t);
}

public class CoordinateSetting {

    /* Расчет вертикального положения тела через 1 сек
     *
     * @param u - начальная скорость тела (м/с)
     * @param a - угол под которым брошено тело
     * @param g - сила гравитации
     * @param t - время движения (с)
     * @param n - 
     */

    private final int n;
    private final int [] coordinatesX, coordinatesY;

    public CoordinateSetting(double u, double a, double g, double t, int n) {        
        double cosA = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(a));
        double sinA = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(a));
        double tpol_100 = 2 * u * sinA / g / 100;

        this.n = n; 
        this.coordinatesX = coordinates(u, g, t, tpol_100, (t1,t2,t3,t4)->t1*t2*t3*10, cosA);
        this.coordinatesY = coordinates(u, g, t, tpol_100, (t1,t2,t3,t4)->1000-(t1*t2*t3-t4*t2*t2/2)*10, sinA);
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public int[] getCoordinatesX() {
        return coordinatesX;
    }

    public int[] getCoordinatesY() {
        return coordinatesY;
    }

    private int[] coordinates(double u, double g, double t, 
            double tpol_100, CoordinateCalculator calculator, double tmp) {        
        return java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0, n)
                .map(i->(int)calculator.calculate(u, t+tpol_100*i, tmp, g))
                .toArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: как по мне, есть ситуации, в которых подобные имена допустимы. Например, если код пишется по математическим формулам из статьи/книги. В этом случае легко сверить код с формулами в источнике. Но в этом случае нужен комментарий при обявлении переменной.

Comment: @ Mikhail Ionkin простите, из какой именно книги/статьи? код пишется программистами и читается программистами. каждый раз предметная область будет разной. то, что очевидно для математика, ссылающегося на "книгу/статью" , не очевидно для того, кто будет разбираться в этом коде. у меня сейчас 4 проекта, каждый из которых имеет абсолютно разную предметную область: финансы, архитектура, инженерия и т.д. мне сразу все книги/статьи читать ?

Comment: @Дмитрий Большое спасибо за уделенное время. Отдельное спасибо за рекомендации, на текущем этапе моего развития - они бесценны.

Comment: Иногда код пишется математиками для математиков. Именно про этот случай я имел в виду. PS: вы, наверно, имеете в виду промышленное программирование: тут я с вами согласен. Однако, обучение в российских вузах нередко идет на заданиях по математике. Одна из главных задач кода: быть понятным тем, кто его будет читать. В абсолютном большинстве случаев это программисты, но не всегда

Comment: @  Mikhail Ionkin если подходить с такой стороны,то вроде как все нормально на первый взгляд, но на самом деле нет.потому как с мотивацией"я же учусь и пишу для себя",можно игнорировать вообще все, ведь этот код никому не нужен и никто никогда его читать не будет,включая того,кто его пишет. только вопрос в том,зачем вы учитесь и чему в итоге научитесь?понимание того,как именовать переменные и придерживаться codestyle - малая доля того, что нужно знать. но само собой это не придет. посему пока вы учитесь, есть возможность получить позитивный опыт, а есть - писать "для себя". решать вам

Comment: @ NNbot не за что, рад, если вам это поможет освоиться в Java. удачи в программировании. и еще... когда будуте смотреть GRASP обратите внимание на information expert - базовый паттерн GRASP. суть вашего вопроса в корне противоречит этому паттерну, потому как его идея в том, что информация обрабатывается там, где хранится. простым языком - с полями класса должны работать его методы, а думать об использовании "общих полей" какого-то класса - тяжелейшее нарушение этого принципа, как и инкапсуляции в целом